# Lodash - dynamically update parameters of a complex object using lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

im trying to set values to an object dynamically passing the attribute that i need to set the value, for example. i need to set name for the object so i need to find this property in the object and set value 'new name'. but some property can be nested for example address.city.name so basically what i need to do is find where the property city is and set the new value to it. if i have one level i could do it easily using something like `object[attribute] = newValue;`
but sometime the property can be in nested object
object[path][attribute] = newValue;
i was able to accomplish this using the function bellow, but i would to know if its possible do this using lodash. I didn't find any function that find the way of the property

```
onEditDataCallback={(rowData, columnId, newValue) => {
                    const path = findPath(rowData, columnId);
                    if (path) {
                        rowData[path][columnId] = newValue;
                    } else {
                        rowData[columnId] = newValue;
                    }

                    return {
                        ...rowData
                    };
                }}

const findPath = (ob, key) => {
    const path = [];
    const keyExists = (obj) => {
        if (!obj || (typeof obj !== 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj))) {
            return false;
        } else if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return true;
        } else if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            let parentKey = path.length ? path.pop() : '';

            for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                path.push(`${parentKey}[${i}]`);
                const result = keyExists(obj[i], key);
                if (result) {
                    return result;
                }
                path.pop();
            }
        } else {
            for (const k in obj) {
                path.push(k);
                const result = keyExists(obj[k], key);
                if (result) {
                    return result;
                }
                path.pop();
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    keyExists(ob);

    return path.join('.');
};
```

this is what im trying to avoid:

```
onEditDataCallback={(rowData, columnId, newValue) => {
                    const temporary = rowData;
                    switch (columnId) {
                        case 'city': {
                            temporary.address.city.name = newValue;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'addressOne': {
                            temporary.address.addressOne = newValue;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'postalCode': {
                            temporary.address.postalCode.key = newValue;
                            break;
                        }
                        default: {
                            temporary[columnId] = newValue;
                        }
                    }
                    return {
                        ...temporary
                

};
            }}
```

Comment: What if there's multiple properties with the same name in the same object?

Comment: that's why i need to find the way of the property {name: "teste", address: {name: "name2"}}. but if i pass the property number for example i need to find where it is and update in the object

Comment: Perhaps [set](https://lodash.com/docs/#set) is what you are looking for.